# Independence of two binomial variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

I am trying to figure out whether these two variables are independent or not, and why.

In the situation of the problem I was given, the number of clients $N$ follows a Poisson distribution of mean $c$. The number of successful clients $X$ has a probability $p$. The number of events is unlimited and each client is independent.

I understand that both the number of successful clients $X$ and the number of unsuccessful clients $Y$ follow a binomial distribution, and that the total numbers of clients $N$ is the addition of those two variables:
$X\sim\operatorname{Bin}(N,p)$ ; $Y\sim\operatorname{Bin}(N,1-p)$ ; $N=X+Y$.

Are $X$ and $Y$ independent, and why?

Comment: Let's see.  Intuitively, two random variables are independent if information about one conveys no information about the other.  Suppose $p=.8$ and $X=800$.  Do you think $Y$ is more likely to be around $200$ or around $800$?

Comment: I really can't say, I was given no numbers. My first reaction was to say that they are independent since the probability of one customer being successful does not affect the probability of another, but the fact that the problem is talking about the total number of successful or unsuccessful customers bothers me. Does the probability of each individual customer translate to the probability of the whole?

Comment: Why do you think the number of successful clients follows a binomial distribution with parameters $N$ and $p$? What does that even mean, if $N$ is a random number of clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than $X\sim\operatorname{Bin}(N,p)$ I would write $X\mid N\sim\operatorname{Bin}(N,p),$ and similarly $Y\mid N\sim\operatorname{Bin}(N,1-p).$

You have
\begin{align}
& \Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y) = \operatorname E(\Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y\mid N)) \\[8pt]
\text{and } & \Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y\mid N=n) = 0 \text{ unless } n = x+y. \\[8pt]
\text{So } & \operatorname E(\Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y\mid N)) \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y\mid N=n)\Pr(N=n) \\[8pt]
= {} & \Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y\mid N=x+y)\Pr(N=x+y) \\
& \text{(All other terms in the sum vanish.)} \\[8pt]
= & \Pr(X=x\mid N) \Pr(N=x+y) \\
& \text{(since conditional on $N=x+y$, the} \\
& \phantom{(}\text{events $X=x$ and $Y=y$ are the same)} \\[8pt]
= {} & \binom{x+y} x p^x(1-p)^y \cdot \frac{\lambda^{x+y} e^{-\lambda}}{(x+y)!} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{(p\lambda)^2 e^{-p\lambda}}{x!} \cdot \frac{((1-p)\lambda)^y e^{(1-p) \lambda}}{y!}
\end{align}
So $X,Y$ are independent Poisson-distributed random variables with expected values $p\lambda$ and $(1-p)\lambda.$

Comment: I don't understand why $P(X=x, Y=y\,|\,N=x+y)P(N=x+y)=P(X=x\,|\,N=x+y)P(N=x+y)$

Comment: @Simple : You have $N=X+Y.$ So in those cases in which $N=x+y,$ the event $\big[ X=x\ \&\ Y=y\big]$ occurs if, and only if, the event $\big[ X=x\big]$ occurs. $\qquad$